# How do I pass custom parameters using a Hadoop MapReduce Configuration object?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am a relative newbie to Hadoop MapReduce. I was trying a variation of the WordCount Sample at http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh/3/hadoop/mapred_tutorial.html . My source file has additional columns and I want to be able to specify on which column the summation  should happen.

In the run(...) method (Line 87 to 116) I have the arguments passed from the command line. I have two additional arguments one that has the delimiter and the next one that has the column position that I want to do the filtering on).

I am setting these values as

```
    if (args.length == 5) {
        conf.set("ipPosition", args[4]);
    }
    if (args.length == 6) {
        conf.set("delimiter", args[5]);
    }
```

However when I try to fetch these values in the configure (line 28 of the sample) method, they are returning null.

```
    public void configure(JobConf job) {
        try {
            String varIpPosition = job.get("ipPosition");
            if (varIpPosition != null) {
                ipPosition = Integer.parseInt(varIpPosition);
            }
            String varDelimiter = job.get("delimiter");
            if (varDelimiter != null) {
                if (varDelimiter == "comma") {
                    lineDelimiter = ",";
                } else {
                    lineDelimiter = " ";
                }
            }
            System.err.println("IP Position" + ipPosition);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.err.println("Error Configuring Job :"
                    + job.get("ipPosition") + " - "
                    + StringUtils.stringifyException(ex));
        }
    }
```

Am I setting the configuration parameters incorrectly, or am I retrieving them incorrectly? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Okay, that was BAD on my part. How do I expect both the If conditions to be true below?

    if (args.length == 5) {
        conf.set("ipPosition", args[4]);
    }
    if (args.length == 6) {
        conf.set("delimiter", args[5]);
    }

Friday evening coding is a BAD idea apparently. After I fixed the conditions, the code is working fine and dandy.

Sorry for the trouble folks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments above. It was a 'code error'. Nothing wrong with the API. The if conditions should be

```
if (args.length >= 5) {
    conf.set("ipPosition", args[4]);
}
if (args.length >= 6) {
    conf.set("delimiter", args[5]);
}
```

Thanks.