# A job's output to multiple files

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming

I have a map and reduce job running. I want to output some data to a file and in the job some data to another file. How can it be achieved. Please help me as I am new to Hadoop map reduce. Can someone give examples?

Comment: possible duplicate of [hadoop method to send output to multiple directories](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19820985/hadoop-method-to-send-output-to-multiple-directories)

Answer (score 0):

There is an `OutputFormat` class called `MultipleOutputFormat` that can be used instead of the *default* `TextOutputFormat`.

As stated in the [documentation](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/MultipleOutputFormat.html):

*This abstract class extends the FileOutputFormat, allowing to write the output data to different output files. There are three basic use cases for this class. Case one: This class is used for a map reduce job with at least one reducer. The reducer wants to write data to different files depending on the actual keys. It is assumed that a key (or value) encodes the actual key (value) and the desired location for the actual key (value). Case two: This class is used for a map only job. The job wants to use an output file name that is either a part of the input file name of the input data, or some derivation of it. Case three: This class is used for a map only job. The job wants to use an output file name that depends on both the keys and the input file name.*

Since this is an abstract class, you'll need to use one of its implementations, most probably [`MultipleTextOutputFormat`](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/MultipleTextOutputFormat.html).

The way a different `OutputFormat` than `TextOutputFormat` is used is by specifying it when creating and configuring the job:

```
Configuration conf = this.getConf();
Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "job-name");
job.setJarByClass(this.class);
job.setMapperClass(mapper.class);
job.setCombinerClass(combiner.class);
job.setReducerClass(reducer.class);
job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
job.setOutputFormatClass(MultipleTextOutputFormat.class);
MultipleTextOutputFotmat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
...
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It gave me an idea.

Comment: I have another question. I want to use a global data structure like HashMap that is available to all jobs. How do I do that?

Comment: You have several examples about how to pass custom parameters through the Configuration object at stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14971825/propagating-custom-configuration-values-in-hadoop, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8457183/passing-parameters-to-map-function-in-hadoop, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9848675/how-do-i-pass-custom-parameters-using-a-hadoop-mapreduce-configuration-object. In these cases, the passed parameter was a simple value; in your case, I think you must itetrate on the HashMap and pass each (key, value) as a single parameter.